# Search for photos without photo date on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, file-search

On Windows 10, it is fairly easy to search for photos taken within some date range. However, I would like to search for all photos that are missing metadata on when the photo was taken. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: In simple terms, you should be able to open `File Explorer`, target a folder hierarchy containing pictures, change the ribbon's View tab from `Large icons` to `Details`, right-click one of the columns and put a check mark in front of `Data taken`.  After that, you can click on the `Date taken` column to sort accordingly.

Comment: @Run5k Of course! Can’t believe I didn’t think of that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **FIle Explorer** search, an empty field is represented by a pair of empty square brackets:

- Click in the Search bar and type:

### DateTaken:=[]

**Source:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators

Answer (score 1):

in case of exchangeable image file format (EXIF) you can try [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) recursively on `yourphotodir`:

on Windows:

```
exiftool -p "$directory/$filename" -if "not $exif:all" -r yourphotodir
```

on Linux - single quotes:

```
exiftool -p '$directory/$filename' -if 'not $exif:all' -r yourphotodir
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).